# Unity2d : auto up and down game object's position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my game logo can auto move in x position ( up and down ) .
I try to make it by scripts but unsuccess :(

Any idea ? big thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

use unity Animation Graph

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbZTgvCE-8I

In case of any more queries do let me know